# Move file from folder to folder

Tags: android, file, gridview, directory, move

I am creating an application in which, I am displaying images from specific folder in custom gridview. I want to move clicked item to another folder. I have absolute path of image from gridview as well absolute path of folder to which i want to move my file. The problem is that I donot know how to move a file from folder in which actual images are stored to another folder. Can someone please tell me code or class with help of which I can move a file from folder to folder. I searched a lot on stackoverflow and found some of codes but that weren't working for my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 ways:

1:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MoveFileExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;

        try{

            File afile =new File("C:\\folderA\\Afile.txt");
            File bfile =new File("C:\\folderB\\Afile.txt");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            //delete the original file
            afile.delete();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

2:

```
import java.io.File;

public class MoveFileExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        try{

           File afile =new File("C:\\folderA\\Afile.txt");

           if(afile.renameTo(new File("C:\\folderB\\" + afile.getName()))){
            System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
           }else{
            System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
           }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Code examples take from here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/

Comment: Good, if it works for you please mark this as an answer, for other people.

Comment: sir i m getting error in FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
FileUtils is underlined with red line

Comment: import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*; this file is not accepting in import so i cant use Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*; is in red line

Comment: tnk u so much sir. i will try it now